# How can I sort the contents of a string list by length descending?

Tags: c#, sorting, tstringlist

I want to sort a string list of phrases by length, descending, so that this:

```
Rory Gallagher
Rod D'Ath
Gerry McAvoy
Lou Martin
```

would end up as:

```
Rory Gallagher
Gerry McAvoy
Lou Martin
Rod D'Ath
```

I wanted to try this first:

```
List<string> slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs;
. . . // populate slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs
slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs = slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length);
```

...but the last line wouldn't compile, and intellisense suggested that I change it to:

```
slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs = (List<string>)slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length);
```

...which I did. It compiles, but throws a runtime exception, namely, "*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.*"

Do I need a fix to this code, or to attack it in a completely different way?

Comment: @Jawad - As before `IEnumerable as List<T>` returns `null` so this doesn't work.

Comment: yes.. `IEnumerable as List<T>` does not work as that is also another way of casting an IENumerable to List... which you cant do. You have to convert IEnumerable to List via `.ToList()` method. (just posting the original comment that I deleted)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs =
    slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I took out the `var` at the start when I formatted your code. It was clearly a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the `List<T>` class is:

```
public class List<T> :  IEnumerable<T>,...
```

`List<T>`  class inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, with `OrderByDescending` returning an `IOrderedEnumerable<out TElement>`—which also inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

The definition of the `IOrderedEnumerable` interface is:

```
public interface IOrderedEnumerable<out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
```

Check this:

```
IEnumerable<string> enumerable1 = new List<string>{ "x","y"};
List<string> list1 = (List<string>)enumerable1; //valid

IEnumerable<string> enumerable2 =new  Collection<string>{ "x","y"};
List<string> list2 = (List<string>)enumerable2; //runtime error
```

It's always true that every `List<T>` or `Collection<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. But it's *not* true to say that every `IEnumerable<T>` is a `List<T>`.

[image]

There wouldn't be a situation which `IOrderedEnumerable<out TElement>` could be cast to a `List`, because they are not in the same hierarchy.

So, as [@cee sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284760/see-sharper) mentioned, we instead have to call the `ToList()` extension method, to convert `IOrderedEnumerable<out TElement>` to a `List<T>`:

```
List<string> list = new List{"x","xx","xxx"}.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();
```

Comment: FYI: When you place e.g., `List<T>` in your response _without_ backticks, Stack Overflow’s markdown interpreter assumes the generic represents HTML—and since e.g., `<T>` is not a valid HTML element, it removes it. I’ve edited your response to include backticks around the type references to mitigate this.